# Text and Image edit on Canvas with save as file

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am working on an application, in which there is requirement for one page where user can
Add/Edit text on canvas and save as file to print/edit it again.

For example:

Add text to canvas, change its fonts, color, size, etc. 
Later I want to add option for inserting the image on canvas.

It is just like MS Paint which is quite big software,here I just need simple canvas, under that a stack panel where I want to add options to edit text (color palette, size, & font).

Please help me out with suggestions & examples. It is not mandatory to use canvas. My objective to text/image edit page, save as file, and editable again.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To save text to a file for later use, use a textBOX and isolated storage. A canvas is mostly to work with shapes, images, and other graphics controls. 
Say you have a textbox named box in xaml.

**XAML**

```
<Textbox x:name="box" />
```

This code below could be in some kind of save click method when a button is clicked.

**C#**

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
 using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream =
 new IsolatedStorageFileStream("box.txt", FileMode.Create, isoFile))
 {
   using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(isoStream))
   {
     sw.Write(box.Text);
   }
  }
 }
```